# How to dynamically modify a text file on a php site in real time

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

I'm currently displaying a txt file on my website which is constantly being modified. Is there any way to display the modifications to the text file on the page in real time so I don't need to set a page refresh timer to see changes?
The full code for my site can be found here.
https://pastebin.com/JauZurS7

```
if (isset($_GET['enSubmit']) && isset($_GET['uname']) && isset($_GET['rname'])){
echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">';
$room=$_GET['rname']; 
$uname=$_GET['uname'];
if (!is_dir($room)) mkdir($room);
$files = scandir($room);
foreach ($files as $user){
    if ($user=='.' || $user=='..') continue;
    $handle=fopen("$room/$user",'r');
    $time = fread($handle, filesize("$room/$user"));
    fclose($handle);
    if ((time()-$time)>1) unlink("$room/$user");
}
$contents='';
$filename="$room.txt";
if (file_exists($filename)){
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);    
}
$handle = fopen("$room/$uname", "w");
fwrite($handle, time());
fclose($handle);

$files = scandir($room);
$users='';
foreach ($files as $user) if ($user!='.' && $user!='..') $users.=$user."\n";

if (isset($_POST['Send'])){
    $text=$_POST['txt'];
    $contents.="$uname: $text";
    $handle = fopen("$filename", "a");
    fwrite($handle, "$uname: $text\n");
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Currently, the chat system works by people sending text which is appended to a text file. The text file is updated but in order for users to see the changes from others they have to refresh the page. To combat this I set up a 10 second refresh timer, however the problem is that people who are typing at that time will have their work removed. I'm thinking of using filemtime to append the txt file but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally want to use javascript(Ajax more specifically) to dynamically load data in the background of the page. This would allow for you to not have to refresh the page etc.. to view and get/send content

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this answer may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.